# Show days from array in table/calendar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a week-per-week schedule for some tasks, and eventually, in the end, I would like to be able to navigate/paginate through the weeks with some arrows.

Here I have printed dates from the current month into the array, and I would like to present them in table cells so they form a calendar of some kind(from Mon to Sun, and later would be great to have the possibility of paginating dynamically through weeks)...any suggestions perhaps?

```js
var getDaysArray = function(year, month) {
  var names = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
  var date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  var result = [];
  while (date.getMonth() == month - 1) {
    result.push(date.getDate() + "-" + names[date.getDay()]);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  console.log(result);
}


getDaysArray(2017, 10);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Sun</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>First week</td>
    <td>Mon (1st...)</td>
    <td>Tue (2nd...)</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second week</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- /table -->
```

Comment: Use this - https://fullcalendar.io/